# Minecraft Voltz Server Error

Tags: java, minecraft

Hello I have run multiple servers before including voltz, but these last few days I haven't been able to get this server to run on my Ubuntu server 12.04 for some reason every time I start it I get this message

" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException "

Please Help Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's an issue with the program itself or with your Java installation, can you tell us what version of Java have you installed and also, what kind of packet you installed (I mean, from OpenJDK or from Oracle).

Comment: Java Version "1.7.0_75" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~trusty1) OpenJDK Client VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Well, check that please:

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get

I suggest you to try to install Oracle Java from how that guide explain

I hope yo have luck ;)

Comment: That's what i used to install everyrhing.

Comment: If you do exactly like this, you can try contacting the program owner, and not Ubuntu Forum, there'll be no problem with your OS; just with the software you installed (Minecraft Voltz)